# authbind equivalent for centos / amazon linux / rhel

Tags: node.js, networking, amazon-ec2

I would like to run a node.js TCP server on port 80 on an Amazon EC2 instance of Amazon Linux.  I have added 80 to the security group, but the problem is letting node.js bind to port 80, which normally requires root permission.

The easiest solution seems to be using authbind, but it isn't accessible from the EC2 yum repo.  Is there an equivalent utility for Amazon Linux?  Or some other workaround for this distro ?  Or is it actually a bad idea to use authbind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little tedious, but if you install gcc you can compile it from source. You can go [here](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/ucgi/~ian/git?p=authbind.git;a=commit;h=7ad50c1428c0a3585e977bb354b7569347d21615) to get the 2.1.1 release. Click the link that says "Snapshot" to get a tar.gz file. I couldn't seem to download it directly using wget (had to download from web browser and then upload), YMMV.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up binding to a higher port and then using iptables to forward port 80 traffic to that port.  Another option was to use an AWS load-balancer from incoming port 80 to a higher port on the ec2 instance.

Comment: Excellent point about the load balancer. If you're in AWS, an ELB should be there anyway in which case it doesn't actually matter which port the server is listening on.

Comment: @Adam Can you point to a tutorial of these two? Both iptables and ALB do no work for me. I'd rather go with the authbind because it's a matter of application and not the system. Therefore, for my service, it will be easier and obvious to anyone maintaining it to know what's going on

Answer (score 1):

If using `systemd`, you can use `AmbientCapabilities` to allow a service to bind to a lower port.

This is done through your service configuration file in the `/etc/systemd/system` directory:

```
[Service]
AmbientCapabilities=CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE
...
```